# Some one has shared folder in Dropbox but the folder is not appearing in my Dropbox

Tags: dropbox

How do I get a folder in my Dropbox list when it has been shared by someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dropbox sharing process is a three step process.

1. First you need to share the folder with the others by entering their Dropbox name or email address.  Note that can NOT share a folder if it is within the Public folder.
2. Second Dropbox will send a acceptance link to the user.
3. The other user accepts the share and then the folder is automatically added to their Dropbox.

So first check that you have accepted the share link, if you have then you may want to have them resend the link.  If you are not getting the link then you should check spam filter in your email as well as have the other person check that they are getting your Username or email correct.

Comment: I got the mail as below and I have visited the link by clicking on somefolder but folder is not added into my Dropbox.

                   **xyz used Dropbox to share some files with you!
Click here to view "somefolder".**

Comment: i am getting similar messages as well, but i can't seem to remove myself from the list or ban this person

Comment: Doesn't seem to answer the question. I have previously shared folders that Dropbox marks as "not added". How to add them back into the local Dropbox folder?